# MPMediaPickerController select song not play

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (void) showMediaPicker
{ 
  MPMediaPickerController *picker =
  [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

  [[picker view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

  picker.delegate      = self;
  picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
  picker.prompt      = NSLocalizedString (@"AddSongsPrompt", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");

 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated: YES];
 [picker release];
}
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection 
{   
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
   [self playSelectedMediaCollection: collection];
}
- (void) playSelectedMediaCollection: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection {

    if (collection.count == 1) {
    NSArray *items = collection.items;
    MPMediaItem *mediaItem =  [items objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([mediaItem isKindOfClass:[MPMediaItem class]]) {
        NSURL *url = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
        AVMutableAudioMix *fadeMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *params = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
        [params setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0 toEndVolume:1 timeRange:
         CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,1))];
        [fadeMix setInputParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:params]];
        [playerItem setAudioMix:fadeMix];
        AVPlayer *newAvPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        [newAvPlayer play];
     }
   }
}
```

This code Build time error is the  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CMTimeMakeWithSeconds", referenced from:
      -[SongFileViewVC playSelectedMediaCollection:] in SongFileViewVC.o
  "_CMTimeRangeMake", referenced from:
      -[SongFileViewVC playSelectedMediaCollection:] in SongFileViewVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How I solve it.

Comment: What if i want to save the song to my document directory??

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the CoreMedia framework to your project, or make sure that it is correctly added and imported if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**I did it using a simple way**

**Add MediaPlayer.framework**

**your .h**

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMusicPlayerController.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMediaPickerController.h>

@interface libraryAccessViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate>
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *player;
    MPMediaPickerController *picker;
}

- (IBAction)pickMedia:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)playMedia:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopMedia:(id)sender;
```

**your .m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    player=[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

    picker=[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

    [picker setDelegate:self];

    picker.prompt=@"Add an audio to your MyVision";
}

- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{    
   [player setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];

   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

//bind below actions with three UIButtons
- (IBAction)pickMedia:(id)sender
{
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)playMedia:(id)sender
{
   [player play];
}

- (IBAction)stopMedia:(id)sender
{
   [player stop];
}
```

Comment: In this code I donot understand Songs means  How to button action work

Comment: @user1081749, It was unused, I edited! Hope now you are clear with.

Comment: @user1081749, If my answer was helpful to you, you can accept it as correct answer.